# How to architect bean retrieval from DAO vs. User Entered Data bean

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

[image: Example Spring Component Architecture]

I am a total newb to Spring.  Even though I understand the concepts of individual annotations (and dependency injection), I am having difficulty "seeing the forest for the trees." Here, in this example, I have a page that has a dropdown box.  It also stores the user's selected option from that box. So there are three beans, only one of which is properly called a domain bean:

1. DropDownEntry *domain
2. SelectedOption (which could be String or a whole DropDownEntry type stored at Session Scope)
3. PageModel (containing a List of #1 above, and a single instance of #2)

Below is an image of my best guess as how to use Spring to:
1. Retrieve a List from the persistence layer via DAO
2. Retrieve/Store the user's selection

Is this design remotely near correct? Is there an alternate "best practices" way to architect this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Spring MVC Forms might be what you are looking for.
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/07/spring-mvc-form-handling-vol-5-select-option-options-tags.html

**Model**

The model is a map of entries for the drop down box.

**Controller**

You can fetch these entries from a database using the DAO Pattern and turn it into a map in a controller class.

**View**

The drop down box is generated using a mix of HTML, a JSP tags and map of 'drop-down' entries.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell. But from the looks of it, you've made things awfully complicated.

My advice: stop drawing UML, re-read the specification, and start coding. Start with a simple model class that represents the selectable entity. Don't name it `DropDownEntry` (unless you're creating software to model dropdowns), but something that actually describes the selectable entity. Don't worry about data access (DAOs) at this point.

Then create a controller class that allows you to render a view that contains the said dropdown UI element. Then pass the selectable entities (as reference data) to the view in the model. Then make the view render the selectable entities appropriately. Then allow the user to post the selection back to your controller.

Once you have this, you can think about saving the selected entity to persistent storage. At that point you will probably find out that you need to link the selected entity to a user etc.

Good luck.

Comment: OK. FWIW, that was accidental UML.